# How to see all the questions I have 'view'ed earlier?

Tags: support

I wish to see all the questions I have 'view'ed so far. I remember seeing a good question on concurrency, but I am not able to google it again. I had neither voted on it or favorited it as well. Any help?

Comment: Your browser keeps a history of pages visited.

Comment: This is technically impossible on the server side, since such data is simply not stored anywhere, so your only option is client side, i.e. with the browser(s) you're using to view the sites.